Visual Studio workflow not working. System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL
I created a Visual Studio workflow for the first time. It is just logging to history "workflow started". When workflow starts it is showing following error:

HTTP to: https://myspserver/sites/site1/_api/sp.utilities.utility.ResolvePrincipalInCurrentContext?input='i%3A0%23.w%7Ccontoso%5CSPFarm'&scopes='15'&sources='15'&inputIsEmailOnly='false'&addToUserInfoList='false'&matchUserInfoList='true'
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could
not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. at
System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

This is dev environment and I know there is SSL error because certificate has expired. But if I create SPD 2010 and SPD 2013 workflows then they work just fine.
How can I make this Visual Studio work with SSL error? Some way to make him ignore SSL error?

I created a self signed certificate and now workflow is not showing any error.
